# Encrypting Syslog Traffic with TLS (SSL) in aix

Tags: aix

rsyslogd-2066: could not load module '/usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so', dlopen: rtld: 0712-001 Symbol rsCStrConstructFromszStrf was referenced       from module /usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so(), but a runtime definition      of the symbol was not found. rtld: 0712-001 Symbol rsCStrAppendStrf was referenced       from module /usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so(), but a runtime definition      of the symbol was not found. rtld: 0712-001 Symbol gnutls_certificate_client_set_retrieve_function was referenced       from module /usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so(), but a runtime definition      of the symbol was not found. rtld: 0712-001 Symbol gnutls_certificate_type_set_priority was referenced       from module /usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so(), but a runtime definition      of the symbol was not found.  [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]

I am getting above error when i am starting the rsyslogd process in aix machine. Please provide the solution for this.

cmd: startsrc -s rsyslogd

Thanks in advance...

```
*.debug /var/log/test   

# make gtls driver the default      
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls       

# certificate files   
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /rsyslog/protected/ca.pem   

$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name         
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # run driver in TLS-only mode     
*.* @@(o)server.example.net:10514 # forward everything to remote server
```

Comment: What is the output of this command: `dump -H -X32_64 /usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so` ?

Comment: root@:/@->dump -H -X32_64 /usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so

    /usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so:

                        ***Loader Section***
                      Loader Header Information
VERSION#         #SYMtableENT     #RELOCent        LENidSTR
0x00000001       0x00000055       0x000000c2       0x0000009b

#IMPfilID        OFFidSTR         LENstrTBL        OFFstrTBL
0x00000006       0x00001130       0x000006f7       0x000011cb

Comment: ***Import File Strings***
INDEX  PATH                          BASE                MEMBER
0      /opt/freeware/lib:/opt/freeware/lib64:/usr/vac/lib:/usr/lib:/lib
1                                    libgnutls.a         libgnutls.so.30
2                                    libpthread.a        shr_xpg5.o
3                                    libc.a              shr.o
4                                    libjson-c.so
5                                    ..

Comment: That won't do; please edit your orginal post and insert the output there, formatted as code. Also you should find out where this `/usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so`  file has come from (installed from lpp, rpm, source, manually copied, etc).